# How to "paint" on an image on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to use an image like this on canvas:

[image]

The user will "paint and fill" the image, but not on top of the outline.

The problem is:
If I put behind the canvas, the paint will cover the outline.
If I put over the canvas the image block canvas interaction.

Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use compositing mode "destination-over" to draw behind existing content (from image, vectors etc.). It's necessary that the existing content provide an alpha channel or composition won't work. If there is no alpha-channel you can [convert inverse luma / matte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40642855/1693593) (the white) to alpha channel.

```js
// a quick-n-dirty demo
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.moveTo(100, 0); ctx.lineTo(150, 150); ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "#09f";

// KEY: composite mode -
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

// draw behind the line
c.onmousemove = function(e) {
  ctx.fillRect(e.clientX - 10, e.clientY - 10, 20, 20);
};
```

```css
body {margin:0}
canvas {border:#777 solid 1px}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) is the example of `drawImage` function. You can draw any preloaded image onto canvas. You can also try to place the `<img>` overlay in front of the canvas and [disable mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for it using `pointer-events: none` CSS property.